# almacenar String en una cadena de datos de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, string

buenas tardes quisiera saber si me podrían ayudar el problema esque creo un arreglo y le vacio datos desde un for pero el arreglo de strings no me los almacena siendo que el de enteros si teniendo el problema en el ARREGLO DE NOTA

```
            parrafo8=document.createElement("input");
            parrafo8.type="text";
            parrafo8.setAttribute("id","pedido"+valor2[i].producto+"-3");
            parrafo8.setAttribute("name","pedido"+valor2[i].producto+"-3");
            parrafo8.setAttribute("value", '');
            parrafo8.placeholder="agregar nota";
            select.appendChild(parrafo);
            parrafo.appendChild(parrafo2);
            parrafo.appendChild(parrafo6);
            parrafo.appendChild(parrafo3);
            parrafo.appendChild(parrafo5);
            parrafo.appendChild(parrafo4);
            parrafo.appendChild(parrafo8);
```

Dentro de la funcion usu tengo un for en el cual saco los valores que anteriormente cree, el problema ocurre cuando en arreglo cantid y produc si almacen correctamente los datos pero el arreglo nota no logra almacenar mas que el primer dato que le ingreso

```
function usu(){

var pedido=document.getElementById("lista-pedido");
var radioid;
var cantid=[];
var produc=[];
var nota=[];


if(pedido.childNodes.length>1){
    var tamaño2=pedido.childNodes.length;
    for(var i=1; i<tamaño2; i++){
        var mesa2=pedido.childNodes[i];
        produc.push(mesa2.getAttribute("value"));
         cantid.push(document.getElementById(mesa2.id+"-1").innerHTML);
         nota.push(document.getElementById(mesa2.id+"-3").value);
    }
    }
```

asi los inserto en la pagina 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero solamente en la base de datos registra el primero y el segundo como una "o" y despues de segundo ya no detecta valores

[image: reflojo de la base de datos]

y asi es como se ve desde el navegador la composición arriba tiene el id compuesto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el código HTML como código y no como imagen

Comment: lo creo desde javascript solo puedo poner el codigo que tengo del navegador

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar `innerHtml`, el cual te trae el elemento del DOM, y reemplazarlo por `textContent` el cual te traerá el contenido como `string`

```
  cantid.push(document.getElementById(mesa2.id+"-1").textContent);
```

Comment: gracias principalmente el problema que tengo se genera en almacenar en el arreglo nota pero si me ayudo tu comentario